# Looking for series that suits 1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1 ..

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm looking for a series that will give me 1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1 ......

The best I came up with is:

$a_n =sin(n\pi/2)+cos(n\pi/2)$

But I am looking for something more elegant. It is important that it will suit for all $n>=0$

Comment: I think most mathematicians would consider $\sin(n\pi/2) + \cos(n\pi/2)$ to be needless obfuscation, even if it's done for the (questionable) purpose of providing a unified closed-form expression.  Probably: $$a_n = \begin{cases} 1, & n \equiv 0~\mathrm{or}~1 \pmod{4}; \\ -1, & n \equiv 2~\mathrm{or}~3 \pmod{4} \end{cases}$$ would be the clearest way to express it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$u_n=(-1)^{\lfloor \frac {n}{2}\rfloor} $$

> or
>   $$u_{2n}=u_{2n+1}=(-1)^n $$

Answer (score 6):

I found the formula $$u_n = i^{n(n-1)}$$ on the OEIS.  It's credited to Bruno Berselli, 2010.

Comment: $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$ seems a more logical way to write it.

Comment: @eyeballfrog More logical?  Logic isn't a continuum; either it's logical or it's not.

Comment: @eyeballfrog this would be a nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n = \sqrt{2} \sin[(2n+1)\pi/4]$

Comment: it is a same as the OP mentioned

Comment: i understand your point, but here we have only one trig function involved.

Answer (score 0):

$$u_0=1$$

$$u_n=(-1)^{n-1}u_{n-1} $$