# Is there a closed form of the sequence 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, ...?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

A closed form for $1, -1, 1, -1, ...$ is $(-1)^n$ for $n=0, 1, 2, ...$
But I can't find a closed form for $1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, ...$

That is: take the first two terms to be $1$, then the next two terms to be $-1$, and the next two terms to be $1$ again, and so ...

Is there a closed form of this sequence? I don't know of any result that can help me find it.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4 + n \pi/2)$.

Comment: There was a comment here that clarified the question; now it's gone. Please include the clarification in the question itself. The question shouldn't rely on comments (especially not deleted ones) to be understood.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2587188/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2604252/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2325377/42969.

Comment: $\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ is such a closed form.

Answer (score 2):

One possible form is:
$$
(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Or using floor:

$$(-1)^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}$$